# Android: Checking Password before starting the app

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

I am creating a simple Android App, in which the first screen would present us with an EditText and a Button, on entering "1234" (quotes not included) in the EditText and then clicking the Button, the app would transfer control to another activity.

Here is the part of the code:

```
final EditText enterPass;
Button submit;
enterPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String pass = enterPass.getText().toString();
            if(pass.contentEquals("1234")){
                Intent adder = new Intent("com.example.pointsadder.Adder");
                  startActivity(adder); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Eclipse is not showing any error in any part of the project at all, but when I run the project, enter "1234" and click on "Submit", **I get the message: "Sorry. The application com.example.adder has unexpectedly ... "**

**EDIT:** This is the log report from DDMS:

```
    [2012-11-08 15:27:52 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:672)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your Log output ? First thing I would try is changing `pass.contentEquals("1234")` just to `pass.equals("1234")`
Also try :

```
Intent adder = new Intent(Password.this, Adder.class);
```

Comment: I am new to Android Development, and do not know where to find the log. Can you give me some instructions as to where to find it?

Comment: Switching to pass.equals("1234") didn't work either, what else can be wrong?

Comment: check the DDMS view for the "logcat" tab. you should see some sort of exception thrown. is your "other activity" listed in AndroidManifest.xml????

Comment: I have added the log, kindly check it.

Comment: Changing the Intent thing worked, but that's what I have used in a previous app, which didn't give any trouble at all. What's wrong. Can you give me little more info on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
if(pass.equals("1234")){
    Intent adder = new Intent("com.example.pointsadder.Adder");
    startActivity(adder);
}
```

Alternatively, you can replace `.equals` with `.equalsIgnoreCase` if you use a case-insensitive password.

Also, you should be declaring your Intent like this:

```
Intent adder = new Intent(Password.this, Adder.class);
startActivity(adder);
```

Comment: Changing the Intent thing worked, but that's what I have used in a previous app, which didn't give any trouble at all. What's wrong. Can you give me little more info on this?

Comment: The app would start with a background image and a background music, wait for sometime and start the next activity using intent. I am not sure of the try and catch statements used, because this is from the tutorials that I use to learn. Here is the code: http://imgur.com/MAASm

Answer (score 0):

```
You should try this:   

 final EditText enterPass;
    Button submit;
    enterPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String pass = enterPass.getText().toString().trim();
                if(pass.equals("1234")){
                    Intent adder = new Intent(PresentActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                      startActivity(adder); 
                }
            }
        });
```

And don't forgot to mention the SecondActivity in Manifest file

Comment: Changing the Intent thing worked, but that's what I have used in a previous app, which didn't give any trouble at all. What's wrong. Can you give me little more info on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pass.equalsIgnoreCase("1234");
```

This may work.
Also change intent syntex with below

```
Intent adder = new Intent(*currentActivity*.this,Adder.class);
startActivity(adder);
```

Also Add Adder activity in **`manifest`** file.

Comment: Changing the Intent thing worked, but that's what I have used in a previous app, which didn't give any trouble at all. What's wrong. Can you give me little more info on this?